# How to match newline or end of file using parser-tools/lex-sre

Tags: racket, lexer

I'm trying to write a lexer in Racket that ignores line comments (i.e., starting from an opening `#` and going 'til the end of the line). The end of the line, in my mind, could be either `#\newline` or `(eof)`, but the following obviously doesn't work as `(eof)` is not valid in this position:

```
(define comment-lexer
  (lexer
    [(:or #\newline (eof))
     (cons `(COMMENT) (main-lexer input-port))]

    [any-char
     (comment-lexer input-port)]))
```

Is it possible to combine them as I'm trying to above, or would I have to write separate rules for each?

It seems to me that whenever you're lexing a potentially multi-line string, you'll have this problem. Is this therefore the wrong approach; should the `(eof)` handling just be done from within the top-most lexer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grammar for the regular expressions that the lexer understands contains the rule:

```
`re ::= ... | (union re ...) `
```

This means `union` expects all subforms to be regular expressions, and since 
`(eof)` is not listed in `re`, it is not a regular expression. In fact `(eof)` is listed as a `trigger`.

Thus `(union #\newline (eof))` is not a regular expression (note that here `:or` is short for `union`).

The conclusion is that you need to move the rule "a line comment starts with a # and ends in a `newline` or an `eof`" to the grammar instead. One way to do it, is to make a lexer rule that turns "# followed by anything not a newline or eof" into a line-comment token. Then in the grammar for the parser, require a line-comment to be followed by newline or eof.